What is wrong with my logical model correct
+---------------------+         +------------------------+
|      Address        |         |   ElectricUtility      |
+---------------------+         +------------------------+
| PostalCode (PK)     |         | ElectricUtilityID (PK) |
| City                |         | ElectricUtility        |
| County              |         +------------------------+
| LegislativeDistrict |
| State               |
| AddressID (PK)      |
+---------------------+

     |                          |
     | 1                        | 1

+----------------------+   +---------------------+
|         CAFV         |   |    EVType           |
+----------------------+   +---------------------+
| CAFVID (PK)          |   | EVTypeID (PK)       |
| CAFVEligibility      |   | EVType              |
+----------------------+   +---------------------+

     | 1
     |

+---------------------+
|    MakeModelYear    |
+---------------------+
| MMYID (PK)          |
| Make                |
| Model               |
| Year                |
| ElectricRange       |
| BaseMSRP            |
+---------------------+

     | 1
     |

+----------------------+
|      Vehicle         |
+----------------------+
| Vin (PK)             |
| DOLVehicleID (PK)    |
| CensusTract2020      |
| CAFVID (FK)          |
| MMYID (FK)           |
| ElectricUtilityID (FK)|
| EVTypeID (FK)        |
| AddressID (FK)       |
| Location             |
+----------------------+

Logical model
